# Trigger Bootstrap modal with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to trigger a Bootstrap modal after a Bootstrap form has been submitted successfully. I have tried using the javascript line, but don't know how to trigger a modal from PHP?

```
<?php
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $contactno = $_POST['contactno'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $roomno = $_POST['roomno'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $town = $_POST['town'];
    $county = $_POST['county'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $floorplan = $_POST['floorplan'];
    $from = 'sentMessage'; 
    $to = 'example.com'; 
    $subject = 'Quote Request';
    $body ="From: $title\n fname : $surname\n conatctno : $email\n roomno : $address\n town : $county\n postcode : \n $floorplan";

// If there are no errors, send the email

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
        setcookie("success","success", time() +100, "/" );
        header('location: index.php');

    }else{
        setcookie("error","error", time() +100, "/" );
        header('location: index.php');
    };

?>
```

Comment: Well, I noticed you set the cookie `success` to the value `success`, use `.indexOf` on `document.cookie` and check if it's there (!== -1), based on that start the modal

Answer (score 0):

Pass a value to the view, like

```
$msg = true;
```

when want to fire the modal. 
check if the variable has been set in javascript:

```
var msg = "<?php echo $msg ?>";
if(msg == "1") {
  // fire here the modal,  like
  $('#hidden-modal-handle').click();
  // where hidden-modal-handle in this case is the id       of the anchor tag that fires the modal
}
```

Put the js code inside $(document).ready  function

Comment: @ Benjamin Gruenbaum,@ jivicab I have got it working now thanks both for your help.